# Fill bookmarks Word footer

Tags: excel, ms-word, footer, bookmarks, vba

I am using Excel VBA to populate bookmarks in Word. I also want to update a bookmark in the footer of the document. Whenever the bookmark is not in the footer, my code works fine. However, when the bookmark in the footer should be populated, I get a `Run-time error '5678' Word cannot find the requested bookmark.`.

I tried recording the code in Word, which gives me the following:

```
Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=Bookmarkname
```

Since I am working from Excel I have changed this code to, where `wordobject = CreateObject("Word.Application")`:

```
wordobject.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=Bookmarkname
```

As stated above, this code works fine when the bookmark is in the 'normal' text. Whenever the bookmark is in the footer, it throws the error.

How can I populate bookmarks in the footer of the Word-document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would probably works, if you manually select all the footer and run it.
However, you are probably not keen on such a solution. In general, using `Selection` in VBA always causes problems sooner or later. Thus, make a favour to your future self and consider avoiding it. [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

This is how to change the Text of any bookmark in Word, including those on the footers and the headers (**works from Word only**):

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestMe()
    Dim bmk As Bookmark
    For Each bmk In ThisDocument.Bookmarks
        If bmk.Name = "wdGoToBookmark" Then
            bmk.Range.Text = "Something new here"
        End If
    Next bmk
End Sub
```

In general, to see info for the bookmarks in the immediate window, a standard loop can help (**works from Word only**):

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim bmk As Bookmark
    For Each bmk In ThisDocument.Bookmarks
        Debug.Print bmk.Name
        Debug.Print bmk.Range.Text
    Next bmk
End Sub
```

If you want to make it **work from Excel**, then you cannot define variables as bookmarks in Excel. But something like this will do the job:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim wordObj     As Object
    Dim wordObjD    As Object

    Dim bmk         As Object
    Dim countBmks   As Long

    Set wordObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wordObjD = wordObj.documents.Add("K:\yourPath\yourFile.docx")
    wordObj.Visible = True

    'Check whether a bookmark exists (FYI):
    Debug.Print wordObjD.bookmarks.exists("someBookmark")

    For Each bmk In wordObjD.Bookmarks
        Debug.Print bmk.Name
        Debug.Print bmk.Range.Text
        If bmk.Name = "TheNameOfTheBookmark" Then
            bmk.Range.Text = "SomeText"
        End If
    Next bmk

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I am always having troubles not using select. Could you please explain the part 'bmk.Name = "wdGoToBookmark" '? How is the name of the bookmark wdGoToBookmark and how can I look for the bookmark with the actual name (bookmarkname) I am looking for?

Comment: @Roosz0rd - the bookmark's name is set to "wdGoToBookmark" manually. The code just changes the text of the bookmark.

Comment: I am getting a Type mismatch on 'If bmk.Name = "wdGoToBookmark" '
But when I use a msgbox(bmk.Name) it does seem to be a string..

Comment: @Roosz0rd - that is strange. Do you have **explicitly** copied and pasted only my code or there is something else there?

Comment: No, since I am working from Excel, ThisDocument.Bookmarks would not work.  
For Each bmk In wordobject.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
          If bmk.Name Is "wdGoToBookmark" Then                   bmk.Range.Text = sBookmarkTekst
End if
next bmk

Comment: @Roosz0rd - I have managed to make it work from Excel as well :)